# Kile editor on Ubuntu 18.04 is not working properly

Tags: 18.04, kde, kile

When I execute 
`$ kile &` 
from the terminal then I get the following message.

```
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/16/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/22/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/24/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/32/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/48/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/64/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/128/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/16/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/22/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/24/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/32/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/48/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/64/"
Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/128/"
kf5.kio.core: Refilling KProtocolInfoFactory cache in the hope to find "mtp"
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Parse error in  "/home/smu/.config/menus/applications-merged/xdg-desktop-menu-dummy.menu" , line  1 , col  1 :  "unexpected end of file"
kf5.kservice.services: The desktop entry file "/usr/share/applications/unity-lens-photos.desktop" has Type= "Application" but no Exec line
kf5.kservice.sycoca: Invalid Service :  "/usr/share/applications/unity-lens-photos.desktop"
kf5.kservice.services: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "ThumbCreator" not found
QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified
kf5.kio.core: We got some errors while running testparm "Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf\nLoaded services file OK.\nWARNING: The 'netbios name' is too long (max. 15 chars).\n\n"
kf5.kio.core: Refilling KProtocolInfoFactory cache in the hope to find "mtp"
kf5.kservice.services: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "ThumbCreator" not found
kf5.kservice.services: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "ThumbCreator" not found
kf5.kservice.services: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "ThumbCreator" not found
kf5.kservice.services: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType "ThumbCreator" not found
```

I can not see the text file. Though I can see messages which appear after latex build etc. latex, pdflatex, okular are all working fine. Please let me know how this can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you:

[Trying to run Kile gives a segmentation fault on Linux Mint 19](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508355/trying-to-run-kile-gives-a-segmentation-fault-on-linux-mint-19)

In short, you will need to install Okular:

```
sudo apt-get install okular
```

It worked great for me.